# In semantic versioning, which version is updated when a module adds compatibility without any breaking changes?

Tags: npm, version, semantic-versioning

I had an `npm` module that was not compatible with `React 18` and `Next.js`. Now, I have made changes to certain sections to ensure compatibility with these packages, without causing any breaking changes for those who were using this module.
After making these changes, which part of the version should be modified: `major` or `minor`?

I read the `Semantic Versioning` document, but unfortunately, I could not find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is React 18 fully compatible with 17 and older versions? If not, then I can say you transitively introduced a breaking change so you should change the major version. Otherwise change the minor version

Comment: Before these changes, my package components were compatible with React 17, and now they are compatible with React version 17 and newer and It is not mandatory for the user to have React 18 installed.

Comment: If it's not mandatory then you didn't introduce a breaking change, so you can bump the minor version.